# Multiple Checkboxes in Formula Field

Tags: formula, opportunity, formula-field, checkbox

I'm sorry if the title is completely butchering what I'm looking for, please let me know if should be updated.

Here's what I'm struggling with:

I have 11 checkboxes on an opp layout. I need the label/name of whatever ones are TRUE to be passed to a single text field.

Ex:
Department 1 ✔️
Department 2 ✔️
Department 3 ✔️

FieldToContainTheDepartmentNames__c should = "Department 1, Department 2, Department 3"

The idea is to essentially "summarize" what departments are being sold into, into a single field vs. having to look at all the checkboxes for a ✔️. I could also then reference this field on a few other objects/places.

I've figured out how to have it check a *single* checkbox field, but not all 11 at once:

```
IF( ED__c = TRUE,"ED","")
```

Comment: It would be a fair bit easier via `Apex Trigger`. Do you have any coding skills? If not you might want to work your way through some Trailhead modules to familiarize yourself with the basics.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't have any Apex coding skills, I've attempted some JS and Python before, but all incredibly rudimentary topics. Do you think after working through some trailhead modules I might actually be able to write it in apex myself? I've done plenty on trailhead, just not much on the dev side of things.

Comment: It depends on how much time you are willing to dedicate. If you don't mind having a trailing comma, then a formula might suffice. But removing that will be trickier than it sounds.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'm not worried one bit about a trailing comma, I'd just like that single field value so it can be passed to other places where the info should be surfaced as well. I can certainly dedicate the time on trailhead, luckily I can set aside time to go through modules at work. I'm leaning towards a formula at this point, at least until I have learned some apex basics to write a trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind a trailing comma, then you can simply use string concatenation. Note that you do not need to compare a checkbox to `TRUE`.

```
IF(Foo__c, "Foo, ", "") & 
IF(Bar__c, "Bar, ", "") & 
IF(Baz__c, "Baz, ", "") & 
IF(Etc__c, "Etc, ", "")
```

Comment: So the IF is already implying that if the listed checkbox "Foo__c" is checked, then display Foo. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep. If the box is checked, the `IF` evaluates true. If it is unchecked, it evaluates false.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly! I forgot one slight addition, along with the checkboxes, there's also a text field for "other department", am I able to somehow add that value on as well, if something gets entered there" I'm assuming I would somehow compare that `Other_Dept__c` to NULL and if false, somehow pass that value through.

Comment: Just concatenate in `& Other_Dept__c` at the end. I think it would treat null as blank, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Concat a bunch of string together

```
IF(Ed__c,"ED,","") + IF(Tom__c,"TOM,","") + ...
```