# Formula and Concatenate Checkboxes without trailing comma

Tags: apex, formula

I am trying to concatenate checkbox values into a comma delimited string but without a trailing comma.  I saw this post here: [Multiple Checkboxes in Formula Field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244361/multiple-checkboxes-in-formula-field), but it does not address the trailing comma.

I have this formula below that I created that works fine, if there are multiple values, but if there is only 1 checkbox selected I get a trailing comma with an output result of "Feb,".  If February is the only checkbox selected in the group, then I would like it to return just "Feb".

How can this be done?

```
IF( Start_January__c = TRUE, 'Jan,', NULL) +
IF( Start_February__c = TRUE, 'Feb,', NULL) +
IF( Start_March__c = TRUE, 'Mar,', NULL) +
IF( Start_April__c = TRUE, 'Apr,', NULL) +
IF( Start_May__c = TRUE, 'May,', NULL) +
IF( Start_June__c = TRUE, 'Jun,', NULL) +
IF( Start_July__c = TRUE, 'Jul,', NULL) +
IF( Start_August__c = TRUE, 'Aug,', NULL) +
IF( Start_September__c = TRUE, 'Sep,', NULL) +
IF( Start_October__c = TRUE, 'Oct,', NULL) +
IF( Start_November__c = TRUE, 'Nov,', NULL) +
IF( Start_December__c = TRUE, 'Dec', NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

That formula will always have a trailing comma if any checkbox is `TRUE`. Moreover there is no need to compare the checkbox's value to `TRUE`.

You could create another formula field that show the value of the first one without the last character.
Let's say that `Foo__c` is your current formula field (the one with the formula in your post that concatenate multiple checkbox value), the formula of the second one would be:
`LEFT(Foo__c,  LEN(Foo__c)-1)`.
While if you have a field that might or might not have a trailing comma the second formula field would be: `IF( RIGHT(Foo__c, 1) = ',' , LEFT(Foo__c,  LEN(Foo__c)-1 ) , Foo__c)`.
Then you could remove `Foo__c` from page layout.
So no matter how many checkbox fields you have, you would only need two formula fields:

1. `Foo__c` - the one that runs against every checkbox.

```
IF( Start_January__c, 'Jan,', '') &
IF( Start_February__c, 'Feb,', '') &
IF( Start_March__c, 'Mar,', '')
...
```

2. `Bar__c` - the one that remove the trailing comma. `LEFT(Foo__c,  LEN(Foo__c)-1)`

By the way, if you aim to use that value in apex code to get a list of string using `.split(',')`, the trailing comma won't be a issue.